# Mysql is using system file cache, not RAM directly

Tags: mysql, caching, memory

I have an Ubuntu 64-bit system and running Mysql version 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log. The machine has 64 GB ram.

I have a pretty huge database which almost has 90 GB of data and one table with 250.000.000 rows.

My problem is, that the mysqld process does not take much memory. Just between 2-5 GB. But the memory of the system is fully used for the file cache.

I restarted the server, there were 63 GB memory free. Once I started to execute larger queries, the amount of free memory decreases, while the amount of file cached increases. 
So mysql is not loading the data in its RAM, but it uses the file cache. 
Queries are very slow. When I query the big table, which - according to explain - uses an index and only has 500.000 rows to consider,  it takes minutes.

Do you have any explanation for this phenomen?

Here is my my.cnf. (This is actually the config of my slave, but it shows exactly the same behaviour) My tables are all InnoDB:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

myisam-recover         = BACKUP

query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

server-id               = 2
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M


[innodb]

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 55G
innodb_log_file_size    = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 4M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_file_per_table = 1  # (this is not respected as I changed it after the first    database was created). So my ibdata1 file is over 80GB in size


max_connections        = 1000                # wenn gleichzeitig viele User zugreifen
table_cache            = 10000                # abgeleitet von max_connections, könnte sogar höher sein
tmp_table_size          = 5000M                # wichtig wg. JOINs, zu kleiner Wert macht die extrem langsam
max_heap_table_size     = 5000M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: Can you please provide the full explain of that query? I don´t believe that your problem is the one you described. That mysql doesn´t use much memory after a restart is normal. Also I would advice, that you go for getting rid of your large single tablespace, it makes a lot of operations way more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the key_buffer size to `128M` and max_allowed_packet to `128M`, as this will speed up the execution of queries

Comment: I assume you are using INNODB, try changing the buffer size under mysqld and see

Comment: Tweaking the key_buffer_size would not help, you can clearly see in OPs question that he only uses InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out was the problem was. The

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 55G

does not belong in the [innodb] section, but in the [mysqld] section.

All the innodb configs needed to be placed in the mysqld section.